# why // (division floor) produces result but math.floor() gives an OverflowError

Tags: python, division, floor

I was solving a programming question, where I was required to find float division of a very large number (10^100,000) with another number (10^5).
However when I was importing floor from math module it gave me a run time error, but when I tried the same using // it showed me the result.

I want to know why such difference?
What is the difference between // and math.floor().

I am a beginner and cannot find related material.

using

using math.floor

```
>>> import math
>>> math.floor( pow(10,1000) / 1000 )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
```

using //

```
pow(10,1000) // 1000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Problem is not in floor. this produce error `pow(10,1000) / 1000`

Answer (score 4):

That's because `pow(10,1000) / 1000` is *floating-point division* and `pow(10,1000) // 1000` is *integer division*.

As you can see, in your case `integer division result [is] too large for a float` because `pow(10,1000) / 1000` attempts to produce a float, but the result will be `10**997`, which won't fit even in a 64-bit float. The double-precision floating-point format (a.k.a. "binary64") is *fixed-width* and allows you to store numbers [up to `10**308`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). If you wanted to store this number anyway, you'd need to use the ["binary80" format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision), which isn't present in Python out-of-the-box and possibly still won't be able to represent the result exactly.

Integer division in Python is different because the `int` type is bounded solely by your RAM. For example, Python can calculate the *integer* `10**10000` (which is `your_huge_number ** 10`!) in a blink of an eye.

Answer (score 1):

`pow(10, 1000)` returns an Integer.

`pow(10, 1000) / 1000` produces the error as it needs to convert `pow(10, 1000)` to a float which it cannot as it is too large.

`pow(10, 1000) // 1000` performs integer division which does not require converting to a floating point number.

Answer (score -1):

```
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
```

This tells you pretty much all you need to know.

`\\` is integer division.  Python will natively use big-integer calculations when numbers get very large, as in this question.

`pow()` however returns floating point numbers.  These adhere to a strict standard defining the format in memory limiting the possible range.  The value you are trying to calculate is outside that range, hence the error.

Comment: Built-in `pow` will return integers when given integer parameters. Only `math.pow` always returns a `float`. Also, the integer division operator is `//`.

Comment: "`pow` [...] returns floating-point numbers" - it doesn't: `pow(10, 10) == 10000000000`

Comment: @TimPietzcker ah, I was indeed thinking of `math.pow()`  thanks